# Can I change the order of summation and limit?

Tags: calculus

Is it true $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 t^n \sin \pi t dt = \int_0^1\frac{\sin \pi t}{1-t}dt$$

I am thinking of using DCT. My question is can I show this using the fact that the partial sum $\sum_{n=0}^N t^n \sin \pi t$ converges uniformly  to $\frac{\sin \pi t}{1-t}$ on $[0,\delta]$ for all $\delta\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Just saying, it's easier with the monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. This follows from the fact that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n$ converges uniformly to $\frac1{1-t}$ on $[0,\delta]$. So, if $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is any bounded function, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^nf(t)$ converges uniformly to $\frac{f(t)}{1-t}$ on $[0,\delta]$.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

If you were not allowed to do it, you could get the beautiful
$$I_n=\int_0^1 t^n \sin (\pi t)\, dt=\frac{\pi  }{n+2} \, _1F_2\left(\frac{n}{2}+1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{n}{2}+2;-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)$$ where the hypergeometric function is related to deformed Bessel functions.

For example
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I_n \\
 0 & \frac{2}{\pi } \\
 1 & \frac{J_{\frac{3}{2}}(\pi )}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 2 & -\frac{4+2 \sqrt{2} \pi ^2 J_{-\frac{3}{2}}(\pi )+\sqrt{2} \pi ^3
   J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(\pi )}{2 \pi ^3} \\
 3 & -\frac{-3 J_{\frac{5}{2}}(\pi )+\pi  J_{\frac{7}{2}}(\pi )}{\sqrt{2} \pi }
\end{array}
\right)$$
and I am not sure that any CAS would be able to compute the infinite summation.

On the other side, doing what you properly thought about
$$\int\frac{\sin (\pi t)}{1-t}\,dt=-\int \frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{x}\,dx=-\int\frac{\sin (y)}{y}\,dy=-\text{Si}(y)$$